# Correct object method calls in Node.js async pipelines

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I want to use some Node.js `async` pipeline operations (such as `parallel` and `waterfall`) to call instance methods inside an object.

I am using the following format to preserve the correct `this` reference inside the pipeline functions, since, normally, inside pipeline functions `this` references the pipeline object itself.

```
var jobThis = this;
async.waterfall(
    [
        function(cb) { jobThis.getParseInstalls(cb); },
        function(prev, cb) { jobThis.getParseIAPs(prev, cb); },
    ],
    callback
);
```

I want the stages of the pipeline to be able to access (but not modify) a settings object belonging to the wrapping object.

I feel like this constitutes bad style. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this goal? Am I simply not supposed to use methods and `async`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I realized that simply using [`function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) was the cleanest way to do this (and also, `self` is a bit clearer than anything else):

```
var self = this;
async.waterfall([
     self.getParseInstalls.bind(self),
     self.doSomethingElse.bind(self),
 ],
 callback
);
```